# Automatically translate images to have same position for an object

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, signal-processing, sift

Let's say you have various images like below.

**Is there a function in Python OpenCV to automatically translate horizontally an image so that the main object has roughly the same position than on a reference image (the first image)?**

In math words, it would be just computing:

```
score[x] = image_correlation(ref_image, image2.translate_horizontally(x))
```

for all possible `x in range(-200,200)` (if the image width is 200)

and take `x` that maximizes this score.

**Before redoing this from scratch, is this feature already present in OpenCV?**

(Using center of mass of images? other techniques involving a `image_correlation` function already present in OpenCV? Or [Scale Invariant Feature Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) techniques?)

---

Example:

reference image:

[image]

image2:

[image] --> automatically translated to --> [image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it quite easily: you must provide a background reference (with only green background in my case) `ref.png`.

Then a background subtraction + center of mass works well:

```
import cv2
import scipy.ndimage as ndi 

backSub = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()  # or backSub = cv.createBackgroundSubtractorKNN()

frame = cv2.imread('ref.png')
backSub.apply(frame)
frame = cv2.imread('1.png')
mask = backSub.apply(frame)
cv2.imwrite('mask.png', mask)
print(ndi.center_of_mass(mask))
```

Result: (63.6349484521314, 164.158143799214)

We can then compare this center of mass for consecutive frames and do the appropriate translation.

[image]